# Instalar software desde código python?

Tags: python

Ando buscando la forma de instalar software de terceros desde código python. Me explico, programé una aplicación que utiliza un archivo que se obtiene al instalar determinada aplicación, de otra forma no se puede acceder a él. 
Existe una manera de realizar la instalación del software mediante código? Suponiendo que descargo el instalador y lo alojo en alguna carpeta, cómo puedo lanzarlo desde un script?
Estuve buscando mucho, pero me temo que ha sido en los lugares incorrectos, porque no he encontrado la solución.

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido la pregunta es muy amplia te invito a leer [ask] para que la [edit] y sea bien recibida por la comunidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En mi opinión hacer eso no es una muy buena idea, lo ideal es agregar dicha aplicación como dependencia de tu app a la hora de instalarla, tienes que tener en cuanta que en la mayoria de los sistemas operativos es necesario que la aplicación corra con permisos de administración para que pueda instalar software, lo cual no es una muy buena idea desde el punto de vista de la seguridad. Pero si en tu caso específico es necesario, puedes hacerlo de varias formas:

**Usando [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)**

Con subrocess.call puedes ejecutar un comando del sistema, que puede ser una llamada al ejecutable que instala el nuevo software, por ejemplo:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["ls", "-l"])
```

Lanza el comando ls con el parametro -l de los entornos tipo UNIX.

**Usando [subprocess.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)**

A partir de Python 3.5 la forma recomendada es usar subprocess.run:

```
from subprocess import run
run(["ls", "-l"])
```

También es posible hacerlo usando [os.system](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system) y otras funciones del modulo [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: Gracias @Cesar !

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, pero responderé acorde a lo que te entendí.

Primero que todo estas el linux, widonws, mac, en que sistema te encuentras? la manera en que los sistemas gestionan sus paquetes es muuuuuy diferente.

En windows por lo general viene con un instalador .msi en la mayoría de los casos y se encarga de instalar el programa, registros etc. no conozco muy bien este sistema porque soy usuario de linux, pero desde el script es solo ejecutar el instalador y ya, se abrirá la ventana de instalación, lo instalas y listo.

En linux es algo diferente, cada distro linux tiene un gestor de paquetes propio y administra sus paquetes de manera diferente, aunque el sistema de archivos jerárquico de linux esta estandarizado, por ende es muy similar entre  todos los sistemas linux, pero el gestor de paquetes tiene su manera particular de gestionar los paquetes(valga la redundancia), un ejemplo de esto es que en debian sus paquetes son extensión .deb y los gestiona el gestor de paquetes *aptitude*, en fedora son .rpm y los gestiona *dnf*, en Gentoo son código fuente y los compila *portage*(emerge) con ayuda de unos script llamados ebuild, si estas en linux solo es llamar al gestor de paquetes desde tu script y que el te instale el programa.

Tienes que tener muy presente los privilegios que maneja el sistema, por ejemplo en linux no puedes instalar nada a menos que tengas los privilegios para eso.

Ahora como haces esto desde python, desde el script tienes que llamar al sistema con la función **exec**, su prototipo es el siguiente:

Esta copiado tal cual aparece en la documentación y solo una pequeña parte, solo fue traducido por mí, puedes ver el original [aquí](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec)

> exec_stmt ::=  "exec" or_expr ["in" expression ["," expression]]
>
> Esta declaración admite la ejecución dinámica en python. La primera expresión debe evaluarse como una cadena unicode, una cadena codificada a latin-1, un archivo objeto abierto, un código objeto o una tupla. Si se trata de una cadena, la cadena se analiza como un conjunto de sentencias de python que luego se ejecuta(a menos que se produzca un error de sintaxis). Si el archivo esta abierto, el archivo se analiza hasta EOF y se ejecuta, si es un código objeto("ejecutable"), simplemente se ejecuta...